# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed "Line Number 1, Column 2"

Tags: html, xml

I'm trying to test out the very beginning of a web page for a catalog utilising the results of a python script. The problem is that I get an error.

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>  
    </head>
    <body>
        Field2: <input type="text" id="field2"><br><br>
        <input type="button" id='script' name="scriptbutton" value=" Run Script " onclick="goPython()">

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script>
            function goPython(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "findbykeywords.py",
                    data: "\"computer\" PricePlusShippingLowest",
                    context: document.body,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        var id = data;
                        document.getElementById("field2").value = data;
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error that occurs when the <kbd>Run Script</kbd> button is pressed is

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
>   Location: file:///home/~~~~~/test.html
>   Line Number 1, Column 2:

EDIT: here is the python code, though I don't think it is relevant as I have tried reducing it to just a print statement and have received the same issue

Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection
import sys

keywords = sys.argv[1]
if (len(sys.argv) > 2):
    sortOrder = sys.argv[2]
else:
    sortOrder = "BestMatch"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    api = Connection(config_file='ebay.yaml', debug=True, siteid="EBAY-US")

    request = {
        'keywords': keywords,
        'itemFilter': [
            {'name': 'condition', 'value': 'new'}
        ],
        'paginationInput': {
            'entriesPerPage': 10,
            'pageNumber': 1
        },
    'sortOrder' : sortOrder

    }


    response = api.execute('findItemsByKeywords', request)
for item in response.reply.searchResult.item:
    print("Title: ",item.title,", Price: ",item.sellingStatus.currentPrice.value, "\n")
```

Comment: HTML isn't XML. How are you trying to parse it?

Comment: Thats what i'm wondering. Im just trying to test the HTML file

Comment: Test it where? You tagged this python, are you using Beautiful Soup?

Comment: Nah its just a python script im trying to run for info on the web page. Im just testing it by opening it in firefox.

Comment: Does the HTML file name by any chance have an XML extension? It shouldn't have, since HTML is not XML

Comment: Nope. Just test.html

Comment: Well, somehow you are contriving to process this file using an XML parser, and it is failing because the file is not XML.

Comment: Does anyone have any insight on how to not do that?

Comment: Please add the code for the python file.

Comment: @user13096477 Do you get the error message directly when you open the HTML file or do you get the error message when you press the button?

Comment: @Progman In the question, it states `The error that occurs when the Run Script button is pressed is...`

Comment: @Zera added the python.